# Adobe form import

Tags: csv, adobe-acrobat, import, forms

I am trying to import data from a tsv into my Adobe form. I am having trouble importing my "Representative" field. Any ideas?

Below is a link to the examples of the files I am working with.

[Google shared docs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IhlkDoetRMlN0Iaxog1fKx6S-PUach9q?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify I am able to import most of the fields from the tsv file, but the "Representative" field will not import.